# What are the Dotfuscator known issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dotfuscator

Are there any known issues to using the Dotfuscator community edition except for it slowing down the execution speed a little bit?

Is there any thing that I should change in my code before using the dotfuscator?

I am not sure but once a client reported a strange behavior that was not happen before a release with dotfuscator, so I give the client the **SAME** release but without a dotfuscator and every thing return to normal.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you explained the issue you have seen, in detail, you would get an answer. As it stands, your question is too broad in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Dotfuscator Community Edition (which only supports renaming), there will not be any hit to performance. Transforms that can negatively impact performance such as control flow obfuscation and string encryption are unfortunately not included in the Community Edition.

As Stecya explained however, renaming can break all sorts of scenarios where the behavior is determined at run-time instead of during static analysis. Just off the top of my head, scenarios that can break include using reflection (either directly, or indirectly by for example using Enum.Parse), having code references in non-code files (such as XAML), and automatic serialization (without explicitly naming data members).

Answer (score 1):

You should carefully use dotfuscator, and obfuscate only that parts that need to be hidden.
For example obfuscation may break code if you are using Reflection